# How can I Embed java code in lua

Tags: java, lua

I want to include my java code in lua language. I try ffi for this but stuck .Can anyone tell me how to include java code in lua? Explain with basic example.

Comment: You have to [create a JVM in C](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) and use the Lua C-API to expose the functions to Lua.

Comment: And [this](https://chsasank.github.io/lua-c-wrapping.html) shows you how to create a module in C that you can use in LUA...

Comment: But the thing is I only java code to be embed in lua...not the c code..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your cases of using Lua with Java, but one of options - compile Lua to JVM bytecode and execute it on JVM, interacting with any Java code.

For interpretation of Lua on JVM you can use:

- [LuaJ](http://www.luaj.org/luaj/3.0/README.html) - Lua interpreter based on the 5.2.x version of Lua;
- [Rembulan](https://github.com/mjanicek/rembulan) - implementation of Lua 5.3 for JVM.

Comment: Actually my use case is that ...there is some logic for encryption-decryption in java which cannot be implemented in lua, so for this use case i want embed my java code in Lua

Comment: In such case I'm not sure, that using of LuaJ will be pretty convenient or generally suitable

Comment: Do you have any idea about ffi for this??

Comment: Unfortunately, in this moment not. Possibly, someone other provide some better solution